# Spring-Session is not creating tables SPRING_SESSION and SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES on its own, but when I create them manually it throws error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

Following error comes when I try to enter login information:

PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'SESSION_ID' in 'field list'

Following query I ran:

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Following is my SpringConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

     @Bean
        public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
            return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
        }

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/newUser",
            "/forgetPassword",
            "/login",
            "/fonts/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().
        /*  antMatchers("/**").*/
            antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
            permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http
            .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
```

Insert command fails and thus i am not able to login to my spring boot app

After I change field To SESSION_ID:

```
SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api_emailer1x`.`SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES`, CONSTRAINT `SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`SESSION_ID`) REFERENCES `SPRING_SESSION` (`PRIMARY_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE); nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api_emailer1x`.`SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES`, CONSTRAINT `SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`SESSION_ID`) REFERENCES `SPRING_SESSION` (`PRIMARY_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Now I am running following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(SESSION_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Now the issue is When I try to login in my spring boot application it comes back to same login page

And SESSION and SESSION_ATTRIBUTES are getting inserted in db. I dont understand this behaviour

---

Answer (score 0):

I not completely sure if this already answers your question but  as the error states the table `SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES` does not have the column `SESSION_ID`.
So my suggestion would be to rename the column `SESSION_PRIMARY_ID` to `SESSION_ID` in the `SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES` table.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(SESSION_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: I actually already tried that, then it gives me foreign key error

Comment: I see. I updated my answer to reference the `SESSION_ID` instead of the `PRIMARY_ID` column of the `SPRING_SESSION` table.